# Self avoiding random walk

Tags: java, arrays

I understand that this question - about ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - has been answered many times and I apologize for posting it again but I can't seem to figure out how to fix the following code. Basically I need to create a self-avoiding walk in a 100x100 lattice, then change the lattice size to 1000x1000 and simulate the walk to see how many steps it takes before trapping itself and not being able to go anywhere. Any help is greatly appreciated

`

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class SelfAvoidingWalk{
public Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args){

    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);      % I get the error here 
    int Trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);      % and here because args[0]




    for (int t = 0; t < Trials; t++) {
        boolean[][] a = new boolean[N][N];   
        int x = N/2, y = N/2;
```

Comment: That indicates that `args` is empty, are you sure you are running it with the arguments correctly?

Comment: You should add a check for the length of args:  `if (args.length < 2) { System.err.println("Usage: SelfAvoidingWalk <N> <Trials>"); System.exit(1);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

This error occurs when you try to acces an index of an array it doesn't have.

In your case

```
int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

this would fail if you haven't passed any arguments on the command line.  I would check how you are running the class.

Comment: Thanks! This helped.